# Custom headerview in grouped tableview in different orientations

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a set up a grouped tableview where i have overridden the following delegate method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

The headerview gets rendered and everything looks fine... in portrait mode.
If i now rotate my device the headerview is now not aligned with the table cells.

This is because the tableview has added more left and right spacing for the cells in landscape than in portrait.

From what i can tell this is not a UIViewAutoresizeMask question because the tableview cells have a varying amount of space on the left and right side depending if the iDevice is in landscape or portrait mode.

I would appreciate ANY solutions / suggestions to this problem!

UPDATE:
The problem seems to be when a tableview has a position x > 0. Notice the difference in left and right space for the table cell.

[image: In portrait mode]

[image: In landscape mode]

First image is in portrait mode
Second is in landscape mode

Comment: It should really work with flexible height and width enabled in the autoresizing mask.

Comment: Well, i have now investigated a little more and these are my findings. H2CO3, you are right, however, there is one peculiar thing i don´t understand and this is the cause of my problems. If i create a tableview which is not as wide as the iDevice window, for example starting at x = 60 the problem with alignment of the custom header occurs. Why is that? The higher the x starting point of the tableview, the higher the offset is between landscape and portrait mode for the headerview

Comment: oh so I see. Should enable the flexible left, right, bottom and top margins as well.

Comment: Tried that, it doesn´t work. There must be something else. I have created a new xcode project with just the basic to test it out. There is something mystical happening when a tableview is added with a frame x starting point > 0

Comment: I´ve updated my question with some screenshots to illustrate better what happens. I dont think the status bar has anything to do with it.

Comment: Oh. If it doesn't work with the autoresizing mask set to flexible margins, I suspect it is a bug.